# Openai gym window wont close on env close

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am trying to implement simple cart pole code but pygame window doesnt close on env.close and freezes. When i try to manually close, it is restarting kernel. This is my code :

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode = "human")
episodes = 5

for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    while not done:
    
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done,truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
    print("Episode:{} Score: {}".format(episode, score))
env.close()
```

I tried to declera env in different cell but nothing changed. I tried to uninstall and reinstall the packages but it same again. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with `env.render()` function. It is not properly closing the window after the simulation is completed. Maybe you can try to add `pygame.quit()` after the while loop. Something like this:

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode = "human")
episodes = 5

for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done,truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward

    print("Episode:{} Score: {}".format(episode, score))

pygame.quit()
env.close()
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: it didnt change anything, I will try to install anaconda and reproduce